# Python3.3 rounding up

Tags: python, python-3.3

In Python I would like to divide two numbers and if the answer is not an integer I want the number to be rounded up to the number above.
For example 100/30 not to give 33.3 but to give 4.
Can anyone suggest how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What about `-100/33`? `-3` or `-4`?

Comment: And what about `10/9.9999`? `1` or `2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the ceil function in math library that python has, but also you can take a look why in a logical sense

```
a = int(100/3) # this will round down to 3
b = 100/3 # b = 33.333333333333336, a and b are not equal

so we can generalize into the following

def ceil(a, b):
    if (b == 0):
        raise Exception("Division By Zero Error!!") # throw an division by zero error
    if int(a/b) != a/b:
        return int(a/b) + 1
    return int(a/b)
```

Comment: Thank you this has worked perfectly and I now also understand the logic.

Comment: @user3130576 one extra condition you might wanna check is that, b can't be 0, i forgot to do it so let me update it again :)

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [`math.ceil()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil) function:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.ceil(100/33)
4
```

Comment: Note that if the question was about Python 2, you'd need to cast the result: `int(math.ceil(float(100)/33))`. This was changed from 2 to 3.