# Shoe size converter function

Tags: python, function

I am trying to make a shoe size converter function. But this program prints weird things like:

```
"You need function shoe_size at 0x030236F0> sized shoes"
```

What do I have to do? Here is my code:

```
 def shoe_size(foot_size):
    shoe_size = (foot_size + 1,5) * 3 / 2
    return shoe_size

foot_size = (input("Enter your foot size: "))

print ("You need " + str(shoe_size) + " sized shoes")
```

Comment: You have to **call** the function, and **pass the argument** - `str(shoe_size(foot_size))` (note parentheses). I suggest you read a Python tutorial.

Comment: Plus you have fix `(foot_size + 1,5) * 3 / 2` expression as you are trying to multiple tuple with int type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few errors or at least potential errors here check the changes I made to the input statement and you usually don't want a variable that is the same name as the function it is in so:

```python
def shoe_size(given_size):
    #foot_size = (foot_size + 1,5) * 3 / 2 #This multiples a tuple (, as .)
    return (given_size + 1.5) * 3 / 2 #returning float (1.5 makes float)

foot_size = int(input("Enter your foot size: ")) 
#figured you wanted a type cast here: used int just change to float if halfs wanted

print ("You need " + str(shoe_size(foot_size)) + " sized shoes") 
#this converts and prints the size: Your original was treating the function as a variable
```

Comment: @TanveerAlam check out [this question about rounding in python3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750297/python3-3-rounding-up) it explains the logic for rounding well

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the `foot_size` variable to your `shoe_size` method in your print statement:`str(show_size(foot_size))`

Answer (score 0):

```
def shoe_size(foot_size):
    shoe_size = (foot_size + 1.5) * 3 / 2
    return shoe_size

foot_size = (input("Enter your foot size: "))

print ("You need " + shoe_size(foot_size) + " sized shoes")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the corrected script:

```
def shoe_size(foot_size):
   shoe_size = (foot_size + 1.5) * 3 / 2
   return shoe_size

foot_size = (input("Enter your foot size: "))

print ("You need " + str(shoe_size(foot_size)) + " sized shoes")
```